# envFrom configmap in Pod template of Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

We want to use `envFrom` inside a Deployment's Pod template like below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myservice
        image: myimage:latest
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
            name: myconfigmap
```

Error msg:

> error: error validating "k8s/deployment.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field name for v1.EnvFromSource

Using K8s 1.7

Edit:
ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
data:
  TEST1: Hello world
  TEST2: test
```

The config map is also shown on the ConfigMaps board in the k8s dashboard.

Comment: I think it is an indentation error in the last line. Add two spaces to the last line (`name: myconfigmap`). (Otherwise in yaml `name:` is not a key of the object `configMapRef`)

Comment: I fixed the indentaion and the config is now accepted in kubectl. But the env variables of the config map do not appear in the pods...

Comment: Share here your configmap to see what values are inside.

Comment: @fiunchinho: ConfigMap added to initial post.

Comment: Is the configmap created on the same namespace where the Deployment was created? Can you share the output of `kubectl describe configmap myconfigmap` and `kubectl describe deploy mydeployment`?

Answer (score 1):

You are also using `extensions/v1beta1`, that `envFrom` parameter may only be available in later versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

yaml file has indentation issue .
try this

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myservice
        image: myimage:latest
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
          name: myconfigmap
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the config map has the key & value pair appropriately along with indentation.
**Key: "Value"**
This is a minute error that will create the configmap but the pod will not be able to read from the configmap.